# how to generate a 403 error in the Debian 10 logs from my authentication form with symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, logging, http-status-code-403, debian-buster

I host my web application on Debian 10 using symfony 5.4.
Users must authenticate to access my application.

I would like to know if it is possible to generate a 403 error in the Debian logs (/var/log/apache/access.log or elsewhere) in case of bad credentials ?

For the moment, the logs show a 'POST 302'  error which does not suit me.

For symfony experts, I use loginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator.

I don't know where I should do this. If it's on the server or in my application?

here is what i tried

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator;

abstract class AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface, InteractiveAuthenticatorInterface{
...

    
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): Response{
...

        return new RedirectResponse($url, 403, ['HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden']);
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You could use the [logger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) to create your own custom log.

Comment: As already mentioned by @msg. A redirect and 403 are not the same and not "combinable"
Try to throw an Exception instead of redirecting,
`throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Forbidden');` from `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception` namescape

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect with a code, the code is ignored because the redirection itself relies on a code in the 300 range (302 in this case).

If you want to give an error response, you can just `throw $exception;`, but there will be no redirect.

However, the application log should already contain the authentication failure. It's located in `/path/to/app/var/log/prod.log` or whatever environment you happen to be running instead of `prod`.

If you do want to log to the system logs, you can use php [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function.